# Preprocessing query in RAG system to obtain relevant part

Tags: nlp, openai-api, large-language-model

I'm building a chatbot that uses files with information regarding some finance topics. For this i'm using RAG with Pinecone as a vector database. I'm also using Microsoft's Semantic Kernel.

My question is the following:
Suppose my query is "Give me a brief summary of the texts that talk about the losses in XY company". Currently, i'm taking that query and performing a search in the database, which gives me the chunks most relevant to the query, and then I input those chunks to a prompt, along with the query, and the LLM gives me a response. My issue with this is that the vector search should be performed with the query "losses in XY company", but instead it contains the irrelevant part "Give me a brief summary of the texts that talk about" , which should be included after the search, inside the prompt. So, do I need to preprocess the queries to perform the search with only the relevant parts? If yes, I assume I need to ask an LLM to do this for me?